# Varnish sending bad "Host" header to Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, varnish

I'm in the early stages of testing [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) 3.0.4 as a new front end for a web service. I have varnish configured to listen on port 88. For its backend it's using an existing apache server running on the same host on port 80.

The trouble I'm having is that when varnish makes a request to apache, it's including ":88" in the `Host` http header (even though it's definitely connecting to apache on port 80.

For example:

1. I request `http://www.myservice.com:88/images/foo.gif`. It makes a request to the backend.
2. The apache backend logs the `HOST` header to the Apache access log - using `%{Host}` in the log file format
3. The access log shows this host header as `www.myservice.com:88`, not `www.myservice.com`.

If I connect to this apache server with telnet and make identical HEAD requests but altering the value of the `Host` header, I see the same behavior that I witness through varnish - i.e. if I include the :88 in the host header, the request returns 404.

I've tried:

- altering `req.http.header.port` and `beresp.http.header.port` to `80`
- altering `req.http.header.host` and `beresp.http.header.host` to `www.myservice.com`.

Seems like I'm missing something obvious.

How do I get varnish to send a proper Host header to apache?

Comment: Please post the relevant portions of your vcl file. Also, what version of varnish?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Varnish leaves the `Host` header completely unmolested by default - it's sending to Apache what was sent to it.  This is intended behavior - Varnish tends not to fiddle with anything unless you tell it to.

To manipulate it, put something like this in your `vcl_recv`, in addition to any conditional logic you need to add:

```
set req.http.Host = "www.myservice.com";
```

Comment: Had this exact problem with Varnish 3.0.5 and this answer didn't work for me unless I did `set req.http.host` in lower-case. Not sure if this is a bug introduced in 3.0.5 or what.